react useRef on component unmount
I am making a social media app and I want to save the last scrollTop of a div in a component before the user changes the page and the component unmounts.
I tried doing this to save the scroll position before unmounting but the myRef is null :
  useEffect(()=>{
        return ()=>{
            saveToDb(myRef.current.scrollTop);
        }
    }, []);


How can I do this?

Your ref is null, because the element is already unmounted, removed from the DOM.
You can save the element before the unmount
  useEffect(()=>{
        const element = myRef.current;
        return () => {
            saveToDb(element.scrollTop);
        }
  }, []);

This way you will save the element. Even if myRef.current changes, you will have its value when the useEffect executes.
But even if you have the element, since it is no longer on the screen, scrollTop will give 0.
What you can do is to replace useEffect with useLayoutEffect. This ensures that the cleanup function will run before React has painted the next changes to the DOM
 useLayoutEffect(()=>{
     return ()=>{
        saveToDb(myRef.current.scrollTop);  
        // no need of additional variable, 
        // you can access myRef.current here, because it is still on the screen
     }
 }, []);

In the newer version of React (19) you can use cleanup functions in ref callbacks.
const ref = useCallback((element) => {
   return () => {
      saveToDb(element.scrollTop);
   }
}, [])
...
<div ref={ref}>...</div>

Required to use useCallback with empty dependency array! Otherwise the cleanup will execute on each render.
Note: The ref must be passed to the element that controls the overflow!
